# ¿Porque solo se envia un mensaje? Socket y Python3

Tags: python-3.x, socket, python-3.7

Mi pregunta quizás sea una tontería, pero estoy empezando con socket, y no encuentro información :S

La aplicación es básicamente un chat, donde los mensajes se envían al servidor y este los reenvía a todos los usuarios que no son el emisor.

Este programa funciona estupendamente si como ip le pongo al cliente y al servidor "localhost". He abierto un No-ip(Cambien he probado con mi ip publica), los puertos en mi router, y desactivado el firewall en ambos ordenadores.

El/Los Cliente/s conectan al servidor, y puedo enviar un primer mensaje, que reciben todos los clientes. pero cuando envío mas mensajes, no ocurre nada, pero la conexión sigue viva entre los clientes y el servidor.

Gracias por su ayuda y sus respuestas de antemano.

***Servidor***

```
import socket
import threading

class ClaseServidor(): 

    def __init__(self):

        # Configuramos el tipo de conexion y nos ponemos a escuchar 
        self.servidor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.servidor.bind(('', 1337))
        self.servidor.listen()
        self.servidor.setblocking(False) # No bloqueamos la conexion (Genera una excepcion si no puede mandar o recibir datos).

        # Ponemos un thread a aceptar las conexiones.
        aceptarConex = threading.Thread(target=self.AceptarConexiones)
        aceptarConex.daemon = True
        aceptarConex.start()

        # Ponemos un thread a leer y reenviar los mensajes entrantes.
        manejoMensajes = threading.Thread(target=self.ManejarMensajesEntrantes)
        manejoMensajes.daemon = True
        manejoMensajes.start()


        # Bucle que mantiene vivo el servidor.
        try:
            while True: 
                Mensaje = input(" =>  ")
                if Mensaje == "salir":
                    self.servidor.close()
                    break
        except:
            self.servidor.close()


    def MandarMensajes(self, mensaje, emisor):

        for receptor in self.listaConexiones:   
            try: 
                # Si la persona que envia el mensaje no es el que lo recibe, envia el mensaje.
                if emisor != receptor:
                    receptor.send(mensaje)
            except:
                # Entramos en la excepcion si no se puede enviar el mensaje a alguien, y lo quitamos de la lista de clientes.
                self.listaConexiones.remove(cliente)


    def AceptarConexiones(self):

        self.listaConexiones = [] # Lista para guardar las conexiones

        while True: # Bucle que mantiene escuchando 
            try:
                clienteConexion, clienteIP = self.servidor.accept() # Empezamos a aceptar conexiones 
                clienteConexion.setblocking(False)
                self.listaConexiones.append(clienteConexion) # Agregamos el objeto cliente a nuestra lista.
                print("se ha conectado el cliente: ", clienteIP[0])
            except:
                pass # Esto es para el setblocking, si se puede aceptar, da una excepcion.


    def ManejarMensajesEntrantes(self):

        while True: # Bucle que mantiene vivo el manejo de mensajes.
            if len(self.listaConexiones) != 0: 
                for cliente in self.listaConexiones: 
                    try:
                        mensaje = cliente.recv(2048) # Recibimos un mensaje.
                        self.MandarMensajes(mensaje, cliente) # Lo mandamos a enviar.
                    except:
                        pass # Esto es para el setblocking, si no recibe un mensaje, da una excepcion.

# --------------------------------------------------------------#

start = ClaseServidor()
```

***Cliente***

```py
import socket
import threading

class ClaseCliente():

    def __init__(self):

        # Configuramos el tipo de conexion y nos conectamos al servidor.
        self.cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.cliente.connect(('mi.dominio.no-ip', 1337))

        self.nick = input("Selecciona tu nombre de usuario: ")

        # Ponemos un thread a recibir los mensajes.
        mensajeRecibido = threading.Thread(target=self.RecibirMensajes)
        mensajeRecibido.daemon = True
        mensajeRecibido.start()

        # Bucle que mantiene vivo el bucle y ademas nos permite enviar mensajes.
        while True:
            mensaje = input()
            try:
                if mensaje != "salir":
                    self.EnviarMensajes(mensaje)
                else:
                    self.cliente.close()
            except:
                self.cliente.close()


    def RecibirMensajes(self):

        while True: # Bucle que mantiene viva la recepcion de mensajes.
            try:
                mensaje = self.cliente.recv(2048)
                print(mensaje.decode()) # Por defecto el encode es "utf-8".
            except:
                pass


    def EnviarMensajes(self, mensaje):

        mensaje = self.nick + "- " + mensaje # Agregamos el nick al mensaje. 
        self.cliente.send(bytes(mensaje.encode())) # Enviamos el mensaje codificado al servidor. Por defecto, en "utf-8".

# --------------------------------------------------------------#


start = ClaseCliente()
```

Comment: He acotado la zona de donde proviene el error. El mensaje se envia de cliente sin fallos, pero el servidor no lo llega a recibir nunca. Sospecho que el problema es del siguiente fragmento.
`mensaje = cliente.recv(2048) # Recibimos un mensaje.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código es correcto y la configuración de red también. El problema provenía de mi ISP, que no me asignaba una IP Publica, sino, una IP privada de una red propia que tenia una IP Publica. Me ofrecían por un precio elevado, tener una IP Publica real, así que la solución fue contratar una VPS y montar allí el servidor con exactamente la misma configuración que indico tener en la pregunta.

La solución al problema: Pregunta a tu ISP si existe algún problema con tener un servidor privado en tu domicilio, si existe, contrata una VPS.

Comment: Para futuros lectores de la pregunta eso que comentas se llama CGNAT y normalmente lo usan los proveedores locales de internet (no los naciaonales como Movistar, Orange, Vodafone...) porque a ellos les cuesta un dinero las IPs publicas y no todo el mundo las necesita, asi que te cobran más si quieres una. Tambien puede afectar a aplicaciones que sean conocidas y usen los mismos puertos, como por ejemplo los grupos de voz de PS4 (si alguien en tu red ya está usando ese puerto, tu consola probablemente ya no pueda y te de fallo de NAT)

Comment: Bastante feo, Estoy en Jazztel, y no es una empresa precisamente pequeña...

Comment: El problema es que ipv4 se nos ha quedado pequeño a todo el mundo y ya no sobran ips así que hasta que ipv6 no coja ritmo....casi nada te garantiza que un proveedor no te meta un cgnat de por medio si no eres empresa o _poweruser_ que no lo evite. No soy ningún experto y quizás me equivoque pero es lo que me he ido encontrando por ahí.

Comment: Tiene mucho sentido eso que comentas. Lo mejor es que si te dedicas a esto pagues de más y te vayas a una empresa que no tenga estos problemas. Movistar y Vodafone me dan este servicio "por defecto". Hoy he llamado a preguntar

Comment: Otro de los problemas del CGNat es que no te puedes poner tampoco domotica ni cámaras ip sin pedirle a tu proveedor que te enrute los puertos dentro de su red. A las malas habla con Jazztel a ver si te abren un puerto y luego abre el mismo en tu router a tu máquina si estás en LAN. Te ahorras el VPS que no es barato tampoco